# How to override default ports in Kestrel

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

i have simple method

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder => builder.UseStartup<Startup>());
        }
```

and i am write appsettings:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
    },
    "Endpoints": {
      "Api": {
        "Url": "https://+:5005",
        "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
      },
      "Grpc": {
        "Url": "http://+:5006",
        "Protocols": "Http2"
      }
    }
  }
```

but when i start app, i see warning:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel", "message": "Overriding address(es) 'https:\/\/localhost:5000, https:\/\/localhost:5001'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.", "addresses": "https:\/\/localhost:5000, https:\/\/localhost:5001
", "methodName": "UseKestrel()" }
```

and app start at standard port 5000, but i expect on port 5005

Why Kestrel changes the start port and how to make the application start on a given https://localhost:5005/api-docs/someService (i am use swagger)

Answer (score 0):

As said on your application startup just do it in `UseKestrel()`

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
       .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder => builder.UseKestrel(x=>x.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5005)).UseStartup<Startup>());
```

Comment: is there any way to use the ports that are already specified in the appsettings

Comment: @gistorx yes, you can define it in appsettings like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configureiconfiguration

Comment: it how i try to get?)))

Answer (score -1):

i am find that i need feel launchSettings.json with

```
"launchUrl": "https://localhost:5005/api-docs/SomeService"
```